# $af = bg \implies f$ and $g$ are the same polynomials with content $a$ and $b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $U$ be a Unique Factorization Domain.  Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two primitive polynomials inside $U[x]$.  Let $a,b \in U$ and now suppose that

$$
af = bg
$$

**Question**: Why does it follow that $a$ and $b$ are the content of the same polynomial in $U[x]$?

I do understand, at least, that since $a, b \in U$, and $af = bg$ that $f$ and $g$ must therefore have the same *degree* (otherwise $ab \ne bg$ since UFD's don't admit zero-divisors).  But this is far from them being the same polynomials with content of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$c(af)=ac(f)=a$ and $c(bg)=bc(g)=b$, so $a=b$... (Here $c(h)$ denotes the content of a polynomial $h$.)